# add data to an element, or create one if it doesnot exist, based on record matching criteria

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Given the following xml file as input:

```
<?xml ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <RECNO>1</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10355</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
            <SUB_A>Some (random) data.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <RECNO>2</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10356</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>19837</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <SUB_A>Some [more] data.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

I would like to insert data into SUB_A element, based on the following criteria:
I have in a tab separated file,

```
value A NUMBER  TOTALS
```

where value A must be entered in the SUB_A element, with a | as a separator, if SUB_A already exists in the record, or to be created, if it does not exist. NUMBER, and TOTALS, are the ones we need, in order to make our match, on the records that the transformation will take place. The value TOTALS, may not exist, at all, sometimes, in our input txt file:

So our transform.txt file looks like:

EDIT:

using the solution kindly mr. Honnen suggested, with the input data suggested, and when i have as input:

```
value i'd like to add   10355   1
another) value i'd like to add  10357   19837
yet another value.] 10358
test    10354
```

i get the below error:

```
       Tree size: 113 nodes, 392 characters, 7 attributes
<line number="10355" totals="1">value i'd like to add</line><line number="10357" totals="19837">another) value i'd like to add</line><line number="10358" totals="">yet another value.]</line><line number="10354" totals="">test</line>
Error at char 6 in xsl:merge-source/@select on line 26 column 65 of merge.xsl:
  XTDE2220: Merge input for source line is not ordered according to merge key, detected at
  key value: ["10354", ""]
  in built-in template rule for /TABLE/DATA[1] in the unnamed mode
  at xsl:apply-templates (/merge.xsl#21)
     processing /TABLE
Merge input for source line is not ordered according to merge key, detected at key value: ["10354", ""]
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <RECNO>1</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10355</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
            <SUB_A>Some (random) data. | value i'd like to add</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <RECNO>2</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10356</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>19837</TOTALS>
            <SUB_A>(another) value i'd like to add</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <SUB_A>Some [more] data. | [yet another value.]</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

what I have tried, would make the question even larger, and has not gotten me close to whatIlook for...

Comment: Are these number values ordere3d as they seem to be in the example? Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? While there are various strategies to solve that it might be a good problem for Saxon 9.8 and the new `xsl:merge` element. In general I would first suggest to morph the tab separated data into XML using `unparsed-text(-lines)` and `tokenize` or `analyze-string`.

Comment: The number values are ordered in the sequence i made the example, but obviously in the real xml, there are also records that do not match at all, so in between the records i have selected, there are also other records in between, that are not affected - transformed. I would prefer such a guidance, saxon is what i use, yes version 9.8 so i should first transform the input file, or it could be done in the same xsl stylesheet?

Comment: The conversion of the textual data to XML can be done in the same stylesheet that merges the data. As for the actual data and that `TOTALS` that can be missing, can that be missing in both the XML input data and the tab separated data? What happens if a RECORD has a certain NUMBER matching a line and TOTALS exists in the RECORD but not the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tried to implement that using [xsl:merge](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merging) from [XSLT 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/), it is not easy to deal with the possibility of a missing totals value as that way you can't use a merge key for that part of the comparison. Also converting the textual data to XML data is prone to mess up the merging if there is any white space additional to the tab characters, for instance in your sample tab data there is white space after the last number and that messes up the merge key, although that could be fixed with normalize-space use or perhaps better by using `analyze-string` instead of `tokenize` to extract the data.

What I have come up with is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    expand-text="yes" version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string">test2017092101.txt</xsl:param>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lines" as="element(line)*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="unparsed-text-lines($text-uri)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(., '&#9;')[normalize-space()]"/>
        <line number="{$tokens[2]}" totals="{$tokens[3]}">{$tokens[1]}</line>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TABLE/DATA">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source name="record" select="RECORD">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="NUMBER"/>
                    <xsl:merge-key select="string(TOTALS)"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-source name="line" select="$lines">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="@number"/>
                    <xsl:merge-key select="string(@totals)"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <xsl:if test="current-merge-group('record')">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="* except SUB_A"/>
                            <SUB_A>
                                <xsl:value-of select="SUB_A, current-merge-group()[2]" separator="|"
                                />
                            </SUB_A>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A sample I tried is

```
value i'd like to add   10355   1
(another) value i'd like to add 10357   19837
[yet another value.]    10358
```

with the input being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="0">
            <RECNO>0</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10354</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
            <SUB_A>Some random data not matched.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <RECNO>1</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10355</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
            <SUB_A>Some (random) data.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <RECNO>2</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10356</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <SUB_A>Some random data not matched.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>19837</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10358</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <SUB_A>Some [more] data.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

and the result then being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
   <DATA RECORDS="2">
      <RECORD>
         <RECNO>0</RECNO>
         <SEQ>0</SEQ>
         <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
         <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
         <NUMBER>10354</NUMBER>
         <CN>PL</CN>
         <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
         <DAYS>0</DAYS>
         <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
         <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
         <SUB_A>Some random data not matched.</SUB_A>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
         <RECNO>1</RECNO>
         <SEQ>0</SEQ>
         <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
         <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
         <NUMBER>10355</NUMBER>
         <CN>PL</CN>
         <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
         <DAYS>0</DAYS>
         <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
         <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
         <SUB_A>Some (random) data.|value i'd like to add</SUB_A>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
         <RECNO>2</RECNO>
         <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
         <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
         <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
         <NUMBER>10356</NUMBER>
         <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
         <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
         <DAYS>10</DAYS>
         <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
         <SUB_A>Some random data not matched.</SUB_A>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
         <RECNO>3</RECNO>
         <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
         <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
         <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
         <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
         <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
         <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
         <DAYS>10</DAYS>
         <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
         <TOTALS>19837</TOTALS>
         <SUB_A>(another) value i'd like to add</SUB_A>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD>
         <RECNO>3</RECNO>
         <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
         <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
         <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
         <NUMBER>10358</NUMBER>
         <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
         <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
         <DAYS>10</DAYS>
         <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
         <SUB_A>Some [more] data.|[yet another value.]</SUB_A>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

It should of course also be possible to use grouping instead of merging to solve that. The code to transform the tabular data to XML would remain the same.

This is getting a bit messy but to not interchange code in comments try to replace the template to create the `line` elements with

```
<xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
    <xsl:variable name="groups" select="analyze-string(., '([^0-9]*?)\s*([0-9]+)(\s*([0-9]+))?')//*:group"/>
    <line number="{$groups[2]}" totals="{$groups[4]}">{$groups[1]}</line>
</xsl:template>
```

that tries to use `analyze-string` instead of `tokenize` but assumes the first column contains no no digits and the second and optional third are composed of digits.

Comment: @sadoyc, I have added the sample data I tested with, try to check that and adapt the code if your data is different, I am not going to download rar files. If you still have problems then try to edit your question with minimal samples trying to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The problem is on my side, using .net version, on windows 10, version 9.8HE, with your sample data, and xml stays unaffected

Comment: Have you set the parameter `<xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string">test2017092101.txt</xsl:param>` to the file name or URL of the text file? Can you add a template `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:message select="$lines"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` to check whether the text files is converted properly to XML elements?

Comment: <line number="" totals="">value i'd like to add   10355   1</line><line number="" totals="">(another) value i'd like to add 10357   19837</line><line number="" totals="">[yet another value.]    10358</line>, output i get on the console, after adding your kindly suggested template, exactly below <xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string">test2017092101.txt</xsl:param>

Comment: So somehow the tokenization is to brittle, at least when copying sample from or to the stackoverflow post. I think the process of converting the text to XML could be more robust by using `analyze-string` instead of `tokenize` but the whole format of that text is underspecified so far to write a good regular expression pattern. Can the text before the two numbers contain any digits?

Comment: there is  a value like 9η έκδ., but i can easily replace it with nineη έκδ., so we have no digits at all in the first column, if this helps, or i can transform input in perhaps two separate files? we do not need to use this third column that causes issues, and only exists in less than 10 occurrences, so we could forget the TOTALS match, and search only for NUMBERS

Comment: Well, the empty attributes in `line number="" totals=""` suggest the second and third column were not detected. See the added template at the end of the answer and try to use that instead of the template in the complete stylesheet and check whether then the `line` elements have attributes with values from the text file.

Comment: i have tried with one more line of data in the txt file, and i get the error i added in my question, using your xsl, and your input data. In real data, i face the same error.

Comment: If the values are not ordered then you would need to set `sort-before-merge="yes"` on the merge sources.

Comment: thank you, in which line and how you would suggest it should be altered?

Comment: If the text file is not ordered then use `<xsl:merge-source name="line" select="$lines" sort-before-merge="yes">`, if the XML is also not ordered then add the same attribute on the other `xsl:merge-source` as well.

Comment: Could someone tell me, how i could keep <RECORD ID="0">, <RECORD ID="1">, <RECORD ID="2"> in the output file?

Comment: I think instead of `<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="* except SUB_A"/>` it should be ``<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except SUB_A"/>`, to copy any attributes.

Comment: worked, also, the output xml would be nice if it could be sorted based on RECORD ID

Comment: I think it is better you ask a new question stating clearly whether you want to sort on the `ID` attribute (which seems to be a number) or the `ID` element (which seems to be some date format).

Comment: just posted a new slightly modified question, thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588096/append-data-ton-an-element-based-on-matching-this-exact-element