# append data ton an element, based on matching this exact element

Tags: xslt-3.0

Given the following XML as input,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
        <RECORD ID="4">
            <RECNO>0</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10354</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>1</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10355</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <RECNO>2</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10356</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <SUB_A>Some random data not matched.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10357</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>19837</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="0">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10358</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

and the following tab separated file:

```
[yet another value.]\t10358
value i'd like to add\t10355
(another) value i'd like to add\t10357
```

i used \t, in order to show where the tab exists in the file. i would like to append the data found in the first column, into the element i try to match on, which in this case in NUMBER.

So if NUMBER equals second column, append to it the value found in the first column, using | as a separator.

how one could have the below result, but with keeping the order of the records, sorting on the  element Output:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="TABLE.DB">
    <DATA RECORDS="2">
          <RECORD ID="0">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10358 | [yet another value.]</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="1">
            <RECNO>3</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10357 | (another) value i'd like to add</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>19837</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="2">
            <RECNO>2</RECNO>
            <SEQUENCE>0</SEQUENCE>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10356</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL 300 L</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>10</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <SUB_A>Some random data not matched.</SUB_A>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="3">
            <RECNO>1</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10355 | value i'd like to add</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
         <RECORD ID="4">
            <RECNO>0</RECNO>
            <SEQ>0</SEQ>
            <DATE>17/12/1999 2:44:08 μμ</DATE>
            <ID>12/11/2015 3:15:25 μμ</ID>
            <NUMBER>10354</NUMBER>
            <CN>PL</CN>
            <PROPERTY>0</PROPERTY>
            <DAYS>0</DAYS>
            <CURRENTSTATUS>0</CURRENTSTATUS>
            <TOTALS>1</TOTALS>
        </RECORD>
    </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

I use Saxon latest, v 9.8

Comment: Is the output you posted the one you want? It is not clear what the sort criteria are, the input and posted output seems to have the same order.

Comment: the output is the one i want, in my real data, if i sort on the NUMBER, then the output has the records messed up, i want to sort on the RECORD ID numbers, the output result. So in the xsl i sort on the RECORD ID, on the NUMBER, and then the result, i need it to be sorted by the RECORD ID number

Comment: Instead of directly outputting the result from the xsl:merge store it in a variable and then sort the contents of the variable, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#sorting, i.e. use `xsl:perform-sort/xsl:sort` on the variable or use `xsl:for-each/xsl:sort`.

Comment: thank you, i would appreciate an xsl example, with the above input output, since i am interested also in the merging action, how this could be done

Answer (score 1):

The `xsl:merge` is similar to your previous question and to sort the merge result you can simply wrap the `xsl:merge` into an `xsl:perform-sort`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    expand-text="yes" version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string">test2017100602.txt</xsl:param>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lines" as="element(line)*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="unparsed-text-lines($text-uri)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(., '&#9;')[normalize-space()]"/>
        <line number="{$tokens[2]}">{$tokens[1]}</line>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TABLE/DATA">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:perform-sort>
                <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(@ID)"/>
                <xsl:merge>
                    <xsl:merge-source name="record" select="RECORD">
                        <xsl:merge-key select="NUMBER"/>
                    </xsl:merge-source>
                    <xsl:merge-source name="line" select="$lines" sort-before-merge="yes">
                        <xsl:merge-key select="@number"/>
                    </xsl:merge-source>
                    <xsl:merge-action>
                        <xsl:if test="current-merge-group('record')">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, NUMBER/preceding-sibling::*"/>
                                <NUMBER>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER, current-merge-group()[2]"
                                        separator=" | "/>
                                </NUMBER>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="NUMBER/following-sibling::*"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:merge-action>
                </xsl:merge>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```